# How can I get my YQL/xpath/javascript to display?

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath, yql

As an exercise, I'm trying to display a tarot card picture, the name of the card, and the meaning on a remote page using YQL/xpath/javascript. I've set up the script like the example on Yahoo but can't get it to display in the browser. Any suggestions as to how to improve it so it will display?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
         function tarot(o){
         var div = o.query.results.div;
         var output = '';
     var title = div[0].strong;
     var content = div[0].p.content;
     var src = div[1].img.src;
     output = "<h3>" + title + "</h3></br><p>" + content + "</p><img src='" + src + "' alt="" />";
    document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = output;
  }
     </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id='results'></div>
      <script src="http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20html%20where%20url%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.tarot.com%2Fdaily%22%20and%20xpath%3D%22%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40id%3D'cardHolder'%5D%20%7C%20%2F%2Fdiv%5B%40id%3D'cardMeaning'%5D%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=tarot"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! 
~Larys

P.S. - I updated the `callback=functionName` part of the code to reflect the most current code. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to fix the problem. Is there something else I seem to be missing?

Answer (score 0):

You have `callback=cbfunc` but you haven't defined `function cbfunc`

Comment: You're right. I looked back at the tutorial and it had called the relevant function with `callback=functionName` but after changing this to `tarot` it didn't seem to help? Is there something else I may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see is that you're never calling your `tarot()` function.

I think you should change your url end to `callback=tarot`

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: You're right, thank you! I did change the `callback` to `tarot` but it didn't seem to help. Do you think there's something else I'm missing?